# Video/voice chat in mobile cross platform

Tags: cross-platform, cordova, rhomobile, titanium-mobile

I am trying to develop an application which can perform video / voice calls between the mobile application.

I am looking forward to develop the application in a cross platform like phonegap, rhomobile, titanium / mosync. Till now in my search I could not find any results on how to use these features.

Answer (score 0):

For RhoMobile, you can see the supported device capabilities [here](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/device-caps#introduction)

Answer (score 0):

MoSync hasn't got video recording support at this point. It's in the road map and will be released for Android and iOS in October, and then in December it will be available for Windows Phone 7, when it is released.